# Check if two 3d mesh are equal in an efficient time

Tags: algorithm, 3d, blender

I'm writing an application that will run on virtual reality. The user will be able to create its own scene, uploading 3d files
For performance reasons, I have to check if I already have the object the user is uploading on my database, or if I have to save it.The
The name of the objects can't be used

I was thinking about using a combination: number of vertices and volume/area of the mesh

But, while the number of vertices is given, I'm struggling to compute the volume or the area for any given mesh

Any suggestion?

Any other option ways to detect two equal meshes is welcomed

Edit:
Since someone suggested it on the comments, the meshes will be very large in number of vertices hence looping for all the vertices is really expensive. I'm looking for a better compromise

Comment: can you find ceter of mass. Mean distance from it. Normalize vertices to have mean distance equals to 1. And then compute variance, then look in your db for an object with almost the same variance. That's not very numerically stable, but with volume you will have the same problem. And what if a model just scaled?

Comment: @Yola That's a good question. I still haven't decided what to do with scaled models. Let's put it on this way: I want to filter as possible all the objects that are the same, but I want to be 100% sure that I'm not considering an object duplicated when it's not

Comment: Compare all the vertices ?

Comment: Why don't ask the user to do this? Just tell her that she can either choose an object from your database or from her own library. In case she uses her own library then she multiplies this object, but if she uses your database then she clones it.

Comment: @NicolasRepiquet I could do that, of course. But It would be really expensive. I want it to be fast, even with some errors, but fast

Comment: @Yola we can't rely on the user for this, he'd always choose to upload a duplicate

Comment: The bmesh module has [calc_volume](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.calc_volume), your problem will come with scale, if a user scales an object by 25% so they can have a bigger character, it will have a different volume even if the mesh is really the same.

Answer (score 3):

Foreach of you mesh, you can compute a hash (CRC64, MD5, ...) on sorted vertices and store it along with other mesh data.

When someone try to add a new mesh to your application, compute its hash, check for meshes with the same hash, and if any, compare vertices/faces to be sure it's exactly the same.

Comment: Hashing is a good idea for sure. Some meshes will have a large number of vertices, is this still a good way? Also, how do I apply CRC64 or MD5 on vectors? (Each vertex is a vector (x,y,z))

Comment: Computing a hash is usualy pretty fast. You can hash the model  file, or convert vectors to bytes and hash that.

Comment: Computing a hash means that if two meshes are the same, but one is rotated or scaled differently, then they will have different hashes.

Comment: If they're scaled, your hash can be the normalized values (take the largest x, y or z, and divide all coordinates components by that). Beware, this is likely to have some weird rounding, which will affect your hash.